# react-native init doesn't make src folder

Tags: react-native

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/react-native-quick-start/step-1-query-based-sync#step-4-create-a-constants-file-and-set-the-realm-instance-address

Many documents including this tutorial refers a `src` folder, but when I create a React Native project with a command like `react-native init MyProject`, it doesn't create `src` folder. Why is that?

Following is my folder structure:

```
├── App.js
├── android
├── app.json
├── index.js
├── ios
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 7):

because react-native-cli do not provide src folder. its up to you, how you design or architect your app. directory structures are upto you and you need to write code accordingly. Generally project specific code always kept in src folder. In your case, there is just one component and App.js is the only file that holds the entire code. but as there will many screens/components you will find it unmanageable. for sake of modularity, src folder is made and used.

```
App
|
|--src
    |
    |--assets
    |--components
    |--screens
          |
          |--loginScreen.jsx
          |--homeScreen.jsx
```

Answer (score 3):

Just manually create your src folder. It's just used to better organize your project.